# Delphi TDBGrid edit inplace with drop down list

Tags: delphi, drop-down-menu, combobox, delphi-7, tdbgrid

I have to do maintenance to an old Delphi v7 application which uses a TDBGrid allowing inplace editting with drop down lists.

The issue is: the grid will show only the values present at data source. Without editting, this would be no problem at all. But if I change some value, the grid will only show the newly set value after updating the underlying register (until that the "old" value is displayed).

This only applies to drop down lists. Other input types (checkboxes, text edits) work without problems.

The edit itself also works fine: the changed values are actually reflected in the datasource when the register is UPDATE'd. My only problem is displaying this not-yet-UPDATE'd value.

I have no idea how to even debug this, or further inspect this behavior. So even if you don't have a complete answer, please indicate what else can I do to find a solution.

**UPDATE**

The project originally used TDB3DGrid (whose source I'm not aware of), but to simplify things I've changed it to TDBGrid. To no avail. The only change was that true/false columns are now displayed as text, and edited as text boxes (displaying and accepting "True" and "False" strings); with TDB3DGrid it showed checkboxes.

Other columns (not edited trough drop down list) are fine: after editing the new value is displayed correctly even before updating the underlying register.

I'm still tracking down where does the list of alternatives that fill the drop down list comes from.

Also still trying to come with an MCVE.

**UPDATE 2**

Apparently the (now) TDBGrid's affected TDBGridColumn has an empty `PickList` property. Sure for designtime. But I think this is not changed in runtime.

TDBGrid's source is a child of a TQuery, whose affected field has `FieldKind` equal to `fkLookup`. Other properties set for the field are `FieldName`, `KeyFields`, `LookupDataSet`, `LookupKeyFields` and `LookupResultField`.

Comment: Did you test this behaviour outside a dropdownlist? I expect it to be the same.

Comment: The only inplace editor support in the standard D7 TDBGrid is for a picklist (see the `Picklist` property of a TColumn in the OLH).  It sounds like custom support for checkboxes, etc, must have been added to the grid(s) in your project, and that raises the question of where the behaviour you want to change is implemented, and how?  If readers don't know that, how can they help?  I think you need an MCVE.

Comment: So, with your updated q text, what is your actual question?

Comment: The same as before: how to show just-edited-values before UPDAT'ing them to the database? This is exactly what one would consider a "normal" behavior in this kind of grid editing. This expected behavior actually occurs on other columns, whose edit style is not a drop down list.